# MariaDb access to file system

Tags: mysql, file, mariadb

I am trying to read a CSV file into MariaDb and get an error message that says "permission denied".  Can you tell me what I have done wrong (see details below)?

I am running MariaDb 10.2.6 on OSX High Serra.  I am logged in to MariaDb as 'root'@'localhost'.   I have granted 'root'@'localhost' FILE privilege. The user 'root'@'localhost' is using the security plugin 'unix_socket'.

I have created a table using the CONNECT storage engine like so:

```
create table twins (
  ABOT double,
  SCLK double,
  LMST varchar(30),
  LTST varchar(30),
  UTC varchar(30),
  HORIZONTAL_WIND_SPEED double,
  VERTICAL_WIND_SPEED double,
  WIND_DIRECTION double,
  AIR_TEMP double)
engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='twins_calib_8066_01.csv'
header=1;
```

The permission to the file I wish to read is:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ssackett  everyone    873837 Mar 20 11:29 twins_calib_8066_01.csv
```

When I issue the SQL: select * from twins;

I receive the error message:

> ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 174 'Open() error 13 on twins_calib_8066_01.csv: Permission denied' from CONNECT

Comment: Bill,  Thanks.  I tried chmod 666 and now all files have RW permission.  I still get the same error.  My best guess at this point is that OSX is trying to authenticate the user 'root'@'localhost' as though it were an account on the host.  So far, though nothing has worked.

Comment: The MariaDb documentation for the FILE privilege among other things says:  "MariaDB server must have the permissions to access those files."     Can you tell me how to setup MariaDB so that the server has "permission to access those files"?

Answer (score 0):

The CSV storage engine doesn't allow UPDATE or DELETE, but it does allow INSERT, therefore mysqld needs write permission on the file, or else it can't open it.

But your CSV file is owned by ssacckett, not "mysql" (or whatever uid your mysqld runs as), so it's not writeable by the mysqld process.

Try:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql twins_calib_8066_01.csv
```

Change it to the user & group that the mysqld process runs as.

Alternatively, change the file mode to writeable by all:

```
chmod 666 twins_calib_8066_01.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission on the directory containing the .csv file.  You need "search" (`x`) permission on the directory to even see the files in it.